# How to concat multiple bash commands?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, macos, concatenation

Having this bash_profile commands, trying to run backend and frontend server in one single alias command i.e `ins`

```
alias is='ivui && npm run start:backend'
alias ib='ivbe && npm run start:dev'
alias ins='ib && is'
```

is referring to a different project folder and it starts the server and ib is also referring to a different folder and server. Trying to concat both, but the first one only triggers and concat of && is not executed.

Concat `npm` helps in combining both servers from single project folder, but wondering how we can get this done using `bash_profile`? so that by executing just `ins`, it must start backend server first and frontend also.

Comment: What happens with the current set up? Does ins not get executed?

Comment: If you run `is` and then `ib` now, will everything start as it should?

Comment: With ins, just ib gets executed and it will not reach to is command. Both are relying on nodemon

Comment: Yes it will run independently @codemonkey not collectively

Comment: Maybe running ib returns a none 0 exit status?

Comment: Yes @Raman it breaks with first command.

Comment: You need to figure out why executing "ivbe && npm run start:dev" is erroring then. There is issue no with the aliasing.

Comment: It don’t throw any error, it is because of nodemon. I should concat multiple nodemon with different repositories through bash commands. I can still make it work making the repo monolithic but that’s not I am looking at. I am looking for a solution where I can start servers Synchronously from different folders in a micro service architecture for Developement purpose

Comment: Is your ultimate goal to start `ivui && npm run start:backend` and `ivbe && npm run start:dev` at the same regardless of the method? Or are you insisting on doing it using aliases only? In the former case, I could suggest doing it differently.

Comment: Please suggest @codemonkey ,

Comment: What if I create a python or shell script and call that using alias or make it executable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your double alias command (`ib && is`) does not work is because, as per `man bash`:

> Aliases allow a string to be substituted for a word when it is used as
> the first word of a simple command.

Stands to reason that if you run `ib && is` where both `ib` and `is` are aliases, it will only run `ib`.

With that out of the way, there is have a different and, I believe, better solution to your problem. You can use `screen` to run those 2 commands in the background and also, as a bonus, have the ability to watch their terminal output any time you want.

The idea is this: 1. Start a `screen` session; 2. Open two windows inside that session; 3. Run `npm run start:backend` in 1st window and run `npm run start:dev` in the second window.

Here is what you need:

```
screen -S Servers -t backend_window -A -d -m
screen -S Servers -X screen -t dev_window
```

This will start a `screen` session with `backend_window` and `dev_window` inside it. Now you just need to run your 2 commands inside those windows:

```
screen -S Servers -p backend_window -X stuff $'npm run start:backend\n'
screen -S Servers -p dev_window -X stuff $'npm run start:dev\n'
```

Now both your npm commands are running in the background at the same time. You can just put these 4 lines into your `.bashrc` file and it will launch on log in.

But the best part about this approach is you can visually see what's going on with those npm commands by attaching the screen and looking inside those windows. Just run:

```
screen -rx Servers
```

This will show you your first window by default. Let's split the screen and show both windows side by side:

```
Ctr-A + | <- will split the screen into 2 sections
Ctr-A + Tab <- will shit cursor to the new section
Ctr-A + " <- will show you your 2 windows, just pick the dev
```

All this will give you this view
[image]

Keep in mind that both your npm commands will continue to run even after you log out. To kill them, either attach the screen as described above and then Ctrl-C both processes. Or just run `killall screen` and they will just die.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function and add your aliases inside, for example,

```
stopdev () (
  cd "$HOME/website" && {
    make website_stop
    ret=$?
    make backend_stop && return $ret
  }
)
```

This example also has a return code, and has a subshell called to run the function, so the filepath is not `$HOME/website` after the function is called.

More information on the following webpage,
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266063/why-cant-i-call-two-aliases-with